# Jquery - How to prevent the loop, when we do click more than 3 times continuously

Tags: jquery, loops, infinite-loop

This has happened in the Responsive menu, click many times when we perform continuous, responsive to open the menu, this will not stop continually open and close.

**Here I give you a simple example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/milindex/uekp0rgr/2/

$(function(){

```
    $('#boton').on('click', function(){ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $('.acction').toggle("slow");
    });
```

});

I have looked at many alternatives and solutions, but seem very complicated, there is some that is easier to understand and implement?

Comment: Your fiddle gives error `event is not defined`

Comment: @RocketR only on Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop the animation:

```
$(function () {
    $('#boton').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.acction').stop().toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: A. Wolff thank you very much, have a good day, oh and a happy new year.